# How to protect/lock materials in library so they don´t change when edited on an object?

Tags: materials

Re: Blender version 3.1

I can´t figure out how to apply a material from my saved asset library without changing it when I adjust/change that material that´s now attached to a mesh.

Example: When applying "Red Metal" to object "Car", I want to make changes to that metal material. But once I do that, I also change the material in the library, which I don´t want.
I want the "original" material in my library to stay the same. I´d like to "lock" it, if you will.
Coming from Keyshot, I am used to dragging and dropping materials onto a mesh, and then editing that material (the one on the mesh) without changing the material in my library.

How do I do this in Blender?

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Don't use assets from "Current file" ... use assets stored in "User Library" like that you can use "Append" to make local changes on material or "Link" type of assigning material if you want keep material sync across multiple files.

Comment: @vklidu, thanks for your response!
I am already doing what you suggest, and I am able to avoid changing the "original" material if I perform a couple of extra steps, like adding the same material to more than one object, clicking the material number ("make single user", I´m guessing) and fiddling about like that. 
But, I´m looking for a way to simply add the material from the asset library without making any changes to the original. Does that make sense?
Perhaps it can´t be done, and it needs a custom script.. :)

Comment: I don't think you got my point ... If you are still looking for answer j will post a couple of images ...